# Update failure for Redmi Note 4

Tags: updates, android-versions, bugs, rom-update

We have two Redmi note 4 phones. In both of them the official update for miui 9 also android nougut (same package total of 1.3 GB) came. In one of the phone it updated smoothly but in the other phone it is displaying - **Try using full rom**

*Interesting fact is that the total 1.3 GB package everytime gets deleted after unsuccessful update attempt*

Tried many times not functioning.

Please help to fix this bug.

Comment: Why don't you contact the redmi officials through email, or call them up?